# Is there a way to link to a specific answer?

Tags: support

Take this question (or any other) for example: [What are the module styles?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/80/what-are-the-module-styles)

Is there a way for me to link to a specific answer?

Comment: I answered this on another meta. http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/104/139

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you would normally see a "Share" button next to the others below the question, but it appears that as we're in "Private" ßeta it's not showing.

When it's visible it looks like this:

[image: Typical StackExchange Share button pop-out]